# Changes in Linux are not taking effect

Tags: linux

i'm new to linux and cloud computing. I am using google cloud. I installed apache as well as mysql. I uploaded a new project to `/var/www/html` and even deleted the default `index.html` however, when I run the site, all I see is default `index.html` even though I deleted it. What could be the problem? I wonder why it is showing. Is there anything I need to do or i'm not doing? I have tried restarting apache but nothing changes. I have also tried clearing browser cache, still nothing.
Navigating to the `/var/www/html` shows that the files there are the ones I uploaded. 
Forgive my question if it sounds naive, I am just trying to learn

Comment: Clear your browser cache?

Comment: @KevinBoone tried that too. It didn't work

Comment: OK. Are you 100% certain that the files in `/var/www/html` are actually the ones in use? I appreciate that this is the default, but there might be something different about the way your Apache HTTP is packaged. Just a wild guess, I'm afraid

Comment: Hang on -- are you just deleting `index.html`, or replacing it?

Comment: What happens if you `curl` the page rather than using a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, find the code block with

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Index FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

You should remove the Index in there then restart your httpd service by

```
sudo service httpd restart
```